# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Domain.User>

Tags: entity-framework, casting

> Compile time error:
> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'Domain.User'.
> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

```
User newUser = uow.UserRepository.Get(u => u.FirstName == "Joah");
```

Then I get a runtime error if I add a cast:

> "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Domain.User]' to type 'Domain.User'."

```
User newUser = (User)uow.UserRepository.Get(u => u.FirstName == "Joah");
```

If I use "var" I see the object being returned but I need to cast it as "User" :-(

Why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are querying and the result is a set where anyone that has the first name of Joah gets returned. What happens if there are multiple results? That is something you may want to consider here.

However, a simple way to fix this is to just take the first one

```
User newUser = uow.UserRepository.Get(u => u.FirstName == "Joah").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: hmm I don't have that method .FirstOrDefault(). Is it because my method GET return an IEnumerable and not IQueryable? this is so confusing

Comment: @Max - IQueryable inherits from IEnumerable just as many different types do ([See here for the MSDN document on FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx). `FirstOrDefault` should be available.

Comment: @Max are you `using System.Linq`?

Comment: after a quick research on the namespace I realized I had to add System.Linq. Thank you! so much to learn ...

Answer (score 0):

`uow.UserRepository.Get(u => u.FirstName == "Joah");`

this is returning a `List` of things (all the people with that first name).

if you just want the *first* one, use

```
User newUser = uow.UserRepository.Get(u => u.FirstName == "Joah").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call toe Get(u => u.FirstName == "Joah") is returning a collection (all users with the first name Joah) and you're trying to set that to the newUser variable.

So that's what's happening.

What will make the code compile is

```
User newUser = uow.UserRepository.Get(u => u.FirstName == "Joah").FirstOrDefault();
```

But remember...

1. That's just the first one it finds. If you have more than 1 user named "Joah" then you might not return the right user.
2. FirstOrDefault() could return null if no item was found. You could use First() instead, which doesn't return null, but does throw an exception when there is nothing found (ie. no User with first name "Joah")